# File Rename With Date (-1 Day)

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to rename a file, with the ending being yesterdays date in `yyyymmdd`.

I'm currently adjusting the date manually each day to be yesterday's date, but is someone able to advise how I could go about scripting this in? I've tried using `Get-Date` and `AddDays(-1)` but I'm receiving errors.

```
gci D:\Temp\ |
    ? {$_.Name -match 'Example'} |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'Example','Example_Example_20180917'}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I think you will also need to make sure the date you have it using the `[DateTime]` format to be able to use `Get-Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to format your `[datetime]` object as a string.

Here is a basic example:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Rename-Item -Path C:\Example.txt -NewName "C:\Example_$($date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt"
```